# How to create category page

Tags: categories

Anybody could help me to make a category page only.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to stick something like this in your theme's `category.php` file:

```
<?php
// fetch the categories with the parent being the current cat
$sub_cats = get_terms('category', array(
    'parent' => get_queried_object_id()
));
if(!is_wp_error($sub_cats) && $sub_cats)
{
    foreach($sub_cats as $cat)
    {
        // Create your grid here, this is just an example
        printf(
            '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
            get_term_link($cat, $cat->taxonomy),
            $cat->name
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Davis. But This just fetch 2 of sub category. For example: cat: cat1, cat2 but cat has 5 sub category (cat1, cat2,...,cat5). Whats wrong? And after user take cat1, that code can not fetch again the sub category [cat1: sub_cat1, sub_cat2,...,sub_cat4]. How make this? Thank you. :)

Comment: Do those other subcategories have posts in them?

Comment: yes, for example: cat: apple
cat1: red apple, cat2: green apple, ..., cat5: blue apple, and sub_cat1: small red apple, ..., sub_cat3: big red apple.
cat
-cat1
--sub_cat1
--sub_cat2
--sub_cat3
-cat2
etc
thank you

Comment: yeah, Solved... 
give more argument because any category is null
'hide_empty' => 0
thx

Answer (score 0):

This may be something you are looking for:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-the-child-category-of-a-specific-parent-category

Which would be something along these lines:

```
$args = array( 'cat' => yourcatid, 'post_parent' => $post->ID, 'number_of_posts' => -1 );

$posts = get_posts($args);

foreach($posts as $post)
{
?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
    <?php echo $post->the_title; ?>
    </a>
    <p><?php echo $post->the_excerpt; ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

This would go into the template you use for the the sub-category

Comment: nothing happened of your solution. Please see the answer above. But little problem occurred. Maybe you've solution. thank you